# Why do I get spam in my newly created email account before even using it?

Tags: email, spam

I made an email account at hotmail.com. Before even using once anywhere I already receive spammail. My question is, how is that possible? And is it unavoidable (from the perspective of an email provider)?

Comment: Is it a short, straightforward and guessable email address? It might be an address that has always received spam in the past, even if it didn't even exist. Spammers often don't care to clean their lists of non-working recipients. Or then it might be an address that someone else used previously, but the account was closed for some reason.

Comment: Well it's "<initial_letter_of_surname>_<lastname>@...", 8 characters long (without the "@..."). You might actually have the correct answer already, I didn't think of those possibilities. I guess my email is guessable enough, though I don't exactly have the most common name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have your answer. Your email address is easily guessable since it follows a very common naming convention. This is a problem today, even for large corporations. The takeaway here, if you're interested, is to avoid using email addresses in applications you use or design, as a log in username. Also, if you are using your email address across multiple applications on the Internet, ensure you are using unique passwords and understand the risk of someone attempting to access those apps (e.g. banks) with credentials they stole somewhere else.